# Fetch data from NewsApi (react, axios)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I've started to learn to react and now I'm working on a code challenge.

My task is to list data from the newsapi.org with Axios. There are 10 articles to be displayed and the list should be extendable (load more).

Now I can't get any further on the point of displaying the data.

Where is my mistake?

Here is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    articles: [],
    isLoading: true,
    errors: null
  };

  getArticles() {
    axios
      .get(
        "http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=ai&apiKey=XXXXXXXXX"
      )
      .then(response =>
        response.data.results.map(article => ({
          date: `${article.publishedAt}`,
          title: `${article.title}`,
          url: `${article.url}`
        }))
      )
      .then(articles => {
        this.setState({
          articles,
          isLoading: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getArticles();
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoading, articles } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h2>#AI</h2>
        <div>
          {!isLoading ? (
            articles.map(article => {
              const { date, title, url } = article;
              return (
                <div key={title}>
                  <p>{date}</p>
                  <p>{title}</p>
                  <p>{url}</p>
                </div>
              );
            })
          ) : (
            <p>Loading...</p>
          )}
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: Hi!
hide your api key ;)

Comment: @AljažMedič delete your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use response.data.**articles** not results

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. But the data still not displayed.

Comment: Try logging the object and see where it stops being what you want it to be...
Also, it is good to check if(response.data.articles), then return

Comment: I agree, debug it step by step. add console.log before manipulating the data.

Comment: Oh god damn guys. The problem was the url.. i changed the http to https and it works. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As Kevin mentioned, first you need to map over `response.data.articles`, but you must also return the mapped results, otherwise when you call `.then` to set the state it'll be `undefined`. Like this:

```
getArticles() {
  axios
    .get(
      "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=ai&apiKey=YOURAPIKEYGOESHERE"
    )
    .then(response => {
      return response.data.articles.map(article => ({
        date: `${article.publishedAt}`,
        title: `${article.title}`,
        url: `${article.url}`
      }));
    })
    .then(articles => {
      this.setState({
        articles,
        isLoading: false
      });
    })
    .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
}
```

That should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Try using the fetch() method see code below.

Part of code from Andrei's robofriends tutorial. Used the same conete

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import CardList from '../components/Cardlist';
import SearchBox from '../components/SearchBox';
import './App.css';
import Scroll from '../components/Scroll';
import ErrorBoundry from '../components/ErrorBoundry';


class App extends Component {
    //add state
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            articles: [],
            searchfield: ''
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        //fetch is a window object
        fetch('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=gb&category=business&apiKey=yourapikey')
        .then(response => response.json()) //convert to json
        //.then(users =>this.setState({ news: users}));
        .then(res => {
            const articles = res.articles;
            // Set state with result
            console.log(articles);
            this.setState({ articles: articles });
          })
    }


    //event for searchbox change
    //not part of react component so use arrow function
    onSearchChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ searchfield: event.target.value})
    }

    render() {
        const filteredNews = this.state.articles.filter(i => {
            return i.source.name.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase()); //change name to source?
        })
        console.log(filteredNews);
        if (this.state.articles.length === 0) {
            return <h1>Loading Robots</h1>
        } else {
            return (
                <div className='tc'>
                    <h1 className='f1'>Top Headlines</h1>
                    <SearchBox  searchChange={this.onSearchChange}/>
                    <Scroll>
                        <ErrorBoundry>
                            <CardList articles={filteredNews}/>
                        </ErrorBoundry> 
                    </Scroll>
                </div>
                
            );
        }
        
    }   
}

export default App;
```